# I am getting this INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY:insufficient access rights on object id:-- for all Campaign Member records

Tags: exception, campaign-member, insufficient-privileges, read-only

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY:insufficient access rights on object id:--

User profile is System Administrator
Marketing User is also checked.

Where can I provide access?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.